# android list adapter does not inflate view correctly

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, layout-inflater

I am trying to use use a customised list view adapter in android so that I can inflate a list of chat message item in a list view with two different layout, left and right message, as shown in the adapter:

```
package com.example.user.normalinterface;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class messageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<chatMessage> {

    private Activity activity;
    private List<chatMessage> messages;

    public messageAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<chatMessage> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.activity = context;
        this.messages = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        int layoutResource = 0; // determined by view type
        chatMessage chatMessage = getItem(position);
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

        if (viewType==0) {
            layoutResource = R.layout.chat_bubble_right;
        } else {
           layoutResource = R.layout.chat_bubble_left;
        }

        if (convertView != null) {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } else {
            Log.d("NOTICE", "generated");
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        //set message content
        holder.message.setText(chatMessage.getContent());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        chatMessage chatMessage = getItem(position);
        if (chatMessage.isMine()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }


    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView message;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_msg);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the class for the chat Message:

```
public class chatMessage {

private String content;
private boolean isMine;

public chatMessage(String content, int senderID, int userID) {
    this.content = content;

    if(userID==senderID)
    {
        isMine = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isMine = false;
    }
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public boolean isMine() {
    return isMine;
}
}
```

Now here's the problem: through logging for each view generated I only find 5 log saying it's generated, it also turns out that only the first 5 view I see on the list view are in the correct layout, here are the screenshots below:

[image: screenshot_1]
[image: screenshot_2]

which in actual fact the order should be:

```
right
left
left
left
right
right
right
```

I have also tried to log the condition for the resource and they are all correct, is somehow that after the first 5 items I viewed layout is no longer correct (I started the list view from below so the first 5 items starting from the bottom are correct). Is there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: You didn't override `getViewTypeCount`

Comment: override it and return 2.

Comment: problem solved! what a silly mistake :P  Selvin can you post the answer below one more time so that I can accept it?